# Cannot import example mongodb using mongoimport

Tags: json, mongodb

I am trying to import an example json file. The json file is - https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mongodb/docs-assets/primer-dataset/primer-dataset.json, and the command I am using in mongo.exe after started running mongod.exe is - 

`"mongoimport --db test --collection restaurants --drop --file C:\MongoDB\Server\3.4\binprimer-dataset.json"`

1) I tried removing "**--drop**" option as there were no collections or anything else loaded.

2) I have loaded the file in the same location as of "mongoimport.exe" location, tried with absolute path and still no luck

It is always giving me the same error that - "**[thread1] SyntaxError: missing ; before statement @(shell)1:14**"

Please help, TIA.

[image]

Comment: Apparently so many people actually do this so it was added to the [manual page](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/) as well *"Run mongoimport from the system command line, **not the mongo shell**."*

Comment: Thanks to you, that worked...